# Buffering video through Lan

Tags: windows, android

Is it possible for a video located on a laptop hdd  to be accessed through wifi using android phone and play it.

If we put file on shared network location and then make it available to others through wifi then why is it still not playable using android phones.

Comment: Some additional info may be helpful, such as how are you trying to play it on androids? What app? What codec is the video using?

Comment: Try installing VLC on the android phones and try that. Otherwise you will need a transcoder on the pc (check out TVersity).